# SQLAlchemy optional ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, database, sqlalchemy

In `SQLAlchemy.orm` I have the following class:

```py
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    src = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('other.id'))
    dst = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('other.id'))

    source = relationship("Other", foreign_keys=[src])
    destination = relationship("Other", foreign_keys=[dst])
```

I want to make the `src` and `source` optional which means those records could be empty in the table. In Django's ORM, I used to make a model field optional by using `blank=True` and `null=True` like:

```py
src = models.ForeignKey(Other, blank=True, null=True)
```

There is a `default` parameter for each column in `SQLAlchemy` as well. I tried:

```py
src = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('other.id'), default=None)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `null=True` in Django ORM is equivalent to `nullable=True` in SQLAlchemy, which is default value. `default=...` serves completely different purpose (see the same documentation page for more info.

*See [Column.nullable](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=column#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.nullable) for more info.*

When you write "it doesn't work" - could you be more specific.

Comment: @van Thanks, that resolved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @van, putting `nullable=True` in the `ForeignKey` not the `relationship` solved my problem:

```py
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    src = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('other.id'), nullable=True)
    dst = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('other.id'))

    source = relationship("Other", foreign_keys=[src])
    destination = relationship("Other", foreign_keys=[dst])
```

creating new instance:

```py
instance = Table(src=None, dst=other)
```